# Can a string literal and a character literal be concatenated?

Tags: c#, java, c++, string, char

Why does `name` misbehave in the following C++ code?

```
string name =  "ab"+'c';
```

How would the equivalent code behave in Java/C#?

Comment: Why not just do std::cout<<"ab" << 'c'; ?

Comment: Since neither java nor C# use cout, they behave by throwing a compile error

Comment: "ab" is not a string, but a char* in c++, they can't be concatenated using the + operator.

Comment: i just wanted to know what is happening

Comment: Do you want to know about C++ or C#? You tagged it C++ but mentioned C# in the question.

Comment: Whoever just edited this post just made everything that's been said completely irrelevant with regards to cout, and removed all reference to C++. . . . hmmmmm

Comment: I couldn't think of a good way to phrase the question so that it makes sense for all three languages and doesn't make the first C++ answers look silly. Any better ideas?

Comment: Er, wait, it looks like my edits have been edited over.

Comment: what about string a = "ab" "c"; i.e if both are string literals, they are concatenated. but if only one, then nope :/ as jalf points out

Comment: @mmyers it's never going to make sense in all 3 languages, as c++ doesn't have strings defined as default, they're in std, and java/C# don't have cout. Bit of an odd question really.

Comment: if both are string literal then compiler error '+' : cannot add two pointers

Comment: of course, you don't put a "+" then

Comment: Gave the question another shot. Is it better now? (Plus added the c# tag to summon Jon Skeet.)

Comment: @litb its work without +.But i dont understand what is happening

Comment: @rajKumar: With "ab" "c", the compiler does the concatenation for you.

Comment: oh ok.Just like that it does?

Comment: It's actually the preprocessor.  Before the compiler even sees the code, the preprocessor runs through and remove comments, applies macros and sticks string literals together.

Comment: @Josh: Yeah, sorry, I usually stay in languages that don't have a preprocessor. In Java, adjacent literals are concatenated at compile time.

Comment: i guess it depends on what compiler you use. GNU cpp does not seem to paste them together. But another one may do so

Comment: but nevertheless it happens at the very start. for example sizeof "12" "34" results in 5 (because type of "1234" is char const[5]), not 3 "34" 2.1 in the standard lists it belonging to some quite early stage so it actually makes me wonder why cpp does not paste them together like Josh describes tho

Comment: True, it may not be in the actual pre-processor and is probably more in the lexer.  I just always think of it as a pre-processor step since it's an easy model to remember and explains the observable behaviour.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation says that in C, it's compile-time. Not that it matters much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
std::string name = "ab" "c";
```

or

```
std::string name = std::string("ab") + c;
```

In C++, "ab" is not a `std::string`, but rather a pointer to a string of chars.  When you add an integral value to a pointer, you get a new pointer that points farther down the string:

```
char *foo = "012345678910121416182022242628303234";
std::string name = foo + ' ';
```

`name` gets set to "3234", since the integer value of ' ' is 32 and 32 characters past the begining of foo is four characters before the end of the string.  If the string was shorter, you'd be trying to access something in undefined memory territory.

The solution to this is to make a std:string out of the character array.  std:strings let you append characters to them as expected:

```
std::string foo = "012345678910121416182022242628303234";
std::string name = foo + ' ';
```

`name` gets set to "012345678910121416182022242628303234 "

Comment: That's not the same thing. There's nothing whatsoever in the original about I/O. He could want to catenate them for creating a name for a semaphore, or something.

Comment: The question has changed significantly from the original question.  I've edited to reflect the change.

Comment: I was just now going to edit the original question back in so answers using std::cout would make sense, but it looks like this was the last one.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that "ab" is not a C++ `std::string`, but a `const char[3]`.
So the + operator it's looking for is `operator+ (const char[3], char)`. That doesn't exist, so the compiler tries letting the array decay to a pointer, so it looks for `operator+ (const char*, char)`. That exists, so the compiler picks that, but it does the wrong thing. Adding an integral value (the char) to a pointer (the const char*) is a common enough operation, and obviously, that's what this operator+ does. The key to understanding this is to realize that the first argument is 1) an array, and 2) a pointer whenever array doesn't make sense. It was used as a string in C as well, yes, but it is not a string. It is a pointer (or occasionally, an array).

There is an `operator+ (const std::string&, char)` which concatenates, but the compiler won't even look for it, because the first argument isn't a std::string.

So a solution is to manually create the string:

```
string name = std::string("ab")+'c';
```

Now the compiler can figure out the correct operator+ to call.

Comment: Voted up, although I think I liked your original better. In C there essentially is no difference between an array and a pointer (except perhaps for allocation/deallocation issues). So its not like it "tries both".

Answer (score 5):

In C++, the compiler is looking for a function with this prototype:

```
T operator+ (const char*, char);
```

Since there isn't one, it can't figure out what T is and can't resolve the `operator<<` call, so it falls back to the only solution left: pointer addition. There is no problem with catenating to a string as in Josh's answer, because a function exists for it.

Comment: It finds one, it's just not the one you'd hope for.  You end up getting pointer arithmetic instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Good point. But the question has changed so many times now, I've lost track of what he's asking.

Answer (score 3):

Given the C++ code:

```
std::string name =  "ab"+'c';
```

The equivalent in Java is:

```
String name = "ab".substring('c');
```

Both promote char to int. Of course in Java it gets range checked and hence throws an exception. In C++ you just get undefined behaviour (or somesuch).

Comment: It's not undefined. It simply adds the integer value of 'c' to the pointer that points to the statically allocated character array {'a', 'b'}. Of course, the result is undefined, but only because you end up pointing past the array. The actual + operation is perfectly well defined

Comment: I believe the act of having a pointer beyond the array+1 is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Java:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("AB" + 'c');
    }
}
```

Output is:

> ABc

Edit:

Actually the compiler hard codes the String ABc...

If you do "AB" + argv[0].charAt(0); to make it use a variable then the compiler does this (basically):

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder;
b.append("AB");
b.append(argv[0].charAt(0));
System.out.println(b.toString());
```

Comment: you forgot the "\n" in the output. It is println() not print()  :)

Comment: And what actually is going on here is that the char literal is casted to string literal before the + operation, which then generates a new string from the "AB" and (String)'c' string literals.

Comment: @OTisler what is a few extra newlines between friends? :-P

Comment: Updated to include the newline :-P and to show what is going on at compile time

Comment: Removed my earlier misleading comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate strings and chars in C# - it's not as strict as C++ I guess.

This works just fine in C#:

```
string test = "foo" + 'b';
```

Comment: It's not strictness, it's just that strings don't technically exist in C++

Answer (score 1):

A C++ compiler doesn't automatically concatenate string-literals with character-literals.  But it will concatenate string-literals with each other.  The syntax is like this:

```
const char * cs = "ab" "c"; // append string-literals
```

As others have mentioned, `string` is not a *built-in* C++ language type.  But there is a `string` type in the C++ Standard Library.  Here are some usage examples:

```
#include <string>
const char * cs = "ab" "c";
std::string s1( cs );
std::string s2( "ab" "c" );
std::string s3 = "ab" "c";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I usually would do in C++ is

string name =  string("ab") +'c';

Remember that the literal "ab" is *not* of type string. What you were doing was hoping that there was no "+" that works between char arrays and chars, and then hoping the compiler could somehow notice that you really want the result to be a std::string, and then go parse your expression on the right hand side for some combination of implicit conversions that could combine with the operator(s) to produce a result of that type. Seems like a rather tall order to me.

Regardless, it doesn't matter. You see, in C the only difference between an array and a pointer is how their memory is allocated. Once you have one, you essentially have an "array/pointer thing". Thus "+" is an operator defined on all arrays and pointers, which takes another argument of any integer type and does pointer math, returning a pointer to that many elements past that spot. Also, in C "char" is really just another kind of integer type. These C design decisions were both useful *hacks*, but as often happens with hacks, they combine with intuitively unexpected results. So all "ab" + 'c' does for you is return an address 99 bytes past wherever the "ab" literal happens to be stored in memory.

Sometimes you can rely on implicit conversions, but you really have to be prepared to help your compiler out a bit at other times.