# C++ Concatenation Oops

Tags: c++, concatenation, cout

So I've been going back and forth from C++, C# and Java lately and well writing some C++ code I did something like this.

```
string LongString = "Long String";

char firstChar = LongString.at(0);
```

And then tried using a method that looks like this,

```
void MethodA(string str)
{    
//some code    
cout << str;    
//some more code }
```

Here's how I implemented it.

```
MethodA("1. "+ firstChar );
```

though perfectly valid in C# and Java this did something weird in C++.

I expected something like

> //1. L

but it gave me part of some other string literal later in the program.

what did I actually do?

I should note I've fixed the mistake so that it prints what I expect but I'm really interested in what I mistakenly did.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a string literal and a character literal be concatenated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635807/can-a-string-literal-and-a-character-literal-be-concatenated)

Comment: @cdhowie thanks for the edit. How do I get syntax highlighting to work? I'd like to do it myself next time.

Comment: @Dan You can view the edited text by clicking the edit link.

Comment: @cdhowie I looked at the text and the diff but I'm having trouble seeing what you did to get syntax highlighting to work. Is there a FAQ or just an invisible character (like tab) I'm missing?

Comment: @Dan Four spaces before each line of code.  Or, enter the code, select it and click the `{}` button on the toolbar, which will apply the four-space indentation for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ does not define addition on string literals as concatenation.  Instead, a string literal *decays* to a pointer to its first element; a single character is interpreted as a numeric value so the result is a pointer offset from one location in the program's read-only memory segment to another.

To get addition as concatenation, use `std::string`:

```
MethodA(std::string() + "1. " + firstChar);
```

Comment: Note that this changes the type of the argument from `const char*` to `std::string` (which might be fine or not depending on the declaration of `MethodA`). Also, equivalent but slightly better: `std::string("1. ") + firstChar`

Answer (score 3):

```
MethodA(std::string("1. ")+ firstChar );
```

since "1. " is const char[4] and has no concat methods)

Answer (score 2):

```
MethodA("1. "+ firstChar );  //your code
```

doesn't do what you want it to do. It is a pointer arithmetic : it just adds an integral value (which is `firstChar`) to the address of string-literal `"1. "`, then the result (which is of `char const*` type) is passed to the function, where it converts into `string` type. Based on the value of `firstChar`, it could invoked undefined behavior. **In fact, in your case, it does invoke undefined behavior, because the resulting pointer points to beyond the string-literal.**

Write this:

```
MethodA(string("1. ")+ firstChar ); //my code
```

Comment: @downvoter: please explain the downvote so I can correct myself.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `"1. "` is a string literal (array of characters), that will decay into a pointer. The character itself is a `char` that can be promoted to an `int`, and addition of a `const char*` and an `int` is defined as calculating a new pointer by offsetting the original pointer by that many positions.

Your code in C++ is calling `MethodA` with the result of adding `(int)firstChar` (ASCII value of the character) to the string literal `"1. "`, which if the value of `firstChar` is greater than 4 (which it probably is) will be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

String literals in C++ are not instances of `std::string`, but rather constant arrays of `char`s. So by adding a `char` to it an implicit cast to character pointer which is then incremented by the numerical value of the character, whick happened to point to another string literal stored in .data section.